# Selenium HtmlUnit: How do I bypass JS errors?

Tags: java, selenium

I have been working on a program for hours and I can't seem to figure out a way to make headless and automated.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(
BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11, true);

driver.get("*Site Removed*"); <-- Exception is called here
```

JavaScript is required for this to work, so I tried this with FirefoxDriver initially to test out the code. It worked fine the moment I switched to HtmlUnitDriver with JS enabled, the program threw an exception stating that it cannot call a method.

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "toLowerCase" of undefined (script in http://***)
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: '**-PC', ip: '***.***.**.**', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
    at com.hazebyte.apple.AppleTest.main(AppleTest.java:26)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "toLowerCase" of undefined (script in http://***)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:865)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:747)
...
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "toLowerCase" of undefined (script in http://***)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3935)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3919)
...
```

The error isn't due to JavaScript being disabled but rather the driver is unable to call methods such as "toLowerCase"

If you have any clues to a fix, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling javascript through the HtmlUnitDriver api:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(
        BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11, true);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

> Please note that to do this you need to change your *driver* variable
>   from a **WebDriver** to an **HtmlUnitDriver**.

---

Alternatively, you could use the DesiredCapabilities for Html Unit with Javascript support:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnitWithJs());
```

I'm still not entirely clear on the impact the DesiredCapabilities have on HtmlUnit, so I am not certain the second option would be viable for your task.  It does exist though, so possibly something to consider and research further if the first setting doesn't work.

Best of Luck.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I miscommunicated. The issue isn't that JavaScript isn't enabled, the issue is that the driver isn't able to call methods of the script when run.

As show by this error...
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "toLowerCase" of undefined.

The code works perfectly fine when I run it as a FirefoxDriver however I am looking to make it headless.

By any chance, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Put all the info you have in the question itself so we can help.

Comment: Hey JeffC, I added more information about the exception as well as cleared up my explanation a bit.

Comment: @Bart, thank you for the clarification.   Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with this level of debugging in web-api's.  If I had to debug this myself I would begin operating on the assumption that in order for the script to run it would need to be on the page.  I'd start with capturing the page source from the driver on error then compare that to the page source from firefox and see if that provided any further leads. Again, I'm not sure if that would do any good. I'll be curious to see how your efforts resolve.